# Link an .obj or .lib to a pre-existing executable

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker

I have a pre-existing executable, for which I have no source, that want to link with an object file or static library (C++), for which I *do* have source.  I'm using Visual Studio 8.0.

The number one thing about this question, please don't ask why I need to do this.  I just want to know how to do it (I'm pretty sure it can be done).

I tried adding the "myprogram.exe" executable to the "additional dependencies" C++ linker project property.  This results in the following linker command line options:

/OUT:"C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SampleCppLibrary\Debug\SampleCppLibrary.lib" /NOLOGO myprogram.exe

When I build the project, I get this error:

`Error  1   fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x268  c:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SampleCppLibrary\SampleCppLibrary\myprogram.exe   1   SampleCppLibrary`

I figured that trying to create a .lib that has an executable linked in might be inherently wrong.  So I changed the project type to be an exe, and I intentionally did not give it a main entry point.  Instead I gave it this:

```
extern int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]);
```

My hope is that the entry point in the pre-existing executable would fill the gap for the linker.  Unfortunately, the error remained unchanged.  Is there something wrong with the concept (and I already know it is completely weird)?  Or perhaps I need to set additional flags to indicate the nature of the exe being linked with?

Answer (score 0):

You can't link an executable as an object - mainly because you can have only one main.

What you probably want to do is call the existing executable as a function from a system() or popen() call in your new app.

edit: if you really need to deliver a single 'exe' I have included a helper program before as a binary resource (ie like an icon) had the caller write it to %temp%, executed it and deleted it!  There are even APIs that create a temp file which can't be seen by other users.

Comment: unfortunately, I can't do that.  I need to add a new entry point to an existing executable - so that there is still only one file when the job is done.  The entry point doesn't even need to invoke any part of the executable (which I know makes my request that much weirder, but please go with it).

Comment: Short of hacking around in it with a hex editor to remove the exe header and insert a lib one I don't see how you can do that. I don't know how well the exe format is documented on win32